# Java File transfer using socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

In my project, I am trying to send a file to every connected clients.I used thread to send file to the clients.But  when I tried to test this I found that 3 clients of total 7 got the complete pdf file but rest of them got only some bytes. What is the efficient way to implement file transfer in java socket programming so that I can send a file to more than 100 clients at the same time?

File Sending code

```
while(true){


            try {
                if(Helper.sendFile)
                {
                    System.out.println("file sending...");
                    File file = new File(Helper.quesPath);
                    // Get the size of the file
                    long length = file.length();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                    int count;
                    while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        System.out.println("ec : "+count);
                    }

                   //out.close();
                   out.flush();
                   in.close();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

File receiving code

```
while (true)
        {
            if(Helper.sendFile)
            {
                try {
                    in = socket.getInputStream();
                    String x=System.getProperty("user.home");

                    out = new FileOutputStream(x+"/Desktop/"+Helper.courseCode+".pdf");
                    System.out.println(x);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[16*1024];

                    int count;
                    while (true) {
                        count = in.read(bytes);
                        System.out.println("v  : "+count);
                        if(count < 16380){
                            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                            break;
                        }else{
                            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("File Done");
                    //in.close();
                    out.close();
                    break;

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("File not found. ");
                }

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Are you unable to use an FTP library? Avoid re-inventing the wheel unless you need some special wheel.

Comment: Agree with you don't reinvent wheels you can just use putty sftp

Comment: This is a simple question on how to transfer data over a socket. There is no reason why the OP shouldn't try to get it to work and learn where the problem could be. He is not reinventing the wheel just learning how socket programming works evidently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you have is in when reading it from the client.

I presume that the magic number 16380 is the expected length of the file. So what you need to do is something a bit different:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 16380) {
      int incoming = in.read(bytes);
      System.out.println("v  : " + incoming);

      if (incoming > 0) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, incoming); 
        count += incoming;
      } else if (incoming < 0) {
        //end of stream
        break; 
      }
}
```

This loop will keep on looping until the number of bytes read (`count`) reaches your magic number.

Something I would also do is use more efficient input streams, like a [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html).

So in your first line in the block you do:

```
in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

If you want a high number of **concurrent** connections it might make sense to look at making your server non-blocking with NIO. But the paradigm is a bit different.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes you are right. I was editing it and for some absent minded reason forgot to put it back in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest these changes:

You can set the `FileOutputStream` to append the received bytes to the file. This way you don't have to make sure that you write them to the correct position.

```
out = new FileOutputStream(x+"/Desktop/"+Helper.courseCode+".pdf", true);
```

The writing of the file can therefore be done like this:

```
int count = 0;
while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    System.out.println("v  : " + count);
    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem you should show us the code in which you handle the sockets.